# Why is my player looking different and not working on my ipad?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I integrated mediaelementjs in a wordpress installation and made an audio playlist. It's working fine in the common browsers even including ie6. but ipad is a no-go.

I have no clue where to start looking, could it have something to do with feature detection?

Also when i navigate to mediaelementjs.com i see an audioplayer that does not resemble the player which is see in my Desktop browsers...

Is mediaelementjs thoroughly tested on ipad?

Answer (score 1):

iPad overtakes any "skinned" audio or HTML5 video skins.  This is to keep Apple's own appearance to keep their branding.  Have an issue with it, take it up with Apple. There is no real way around it when dealing with media.
The skins will only work for desktop browsers.